# Naked partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations, partial-classes

I'm trying to addsome Data Annotation using a Partial Class.

As you can see I added a Test Property to my Partial Class so I can test if it really match with the other partials
(as following this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx)

It seems that my class is a **naked partial class** so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The problem is the MetaData do not apply to the Partial Class (so the Partial Class is ignored)

Could you please help me out? Thanks

```
    using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        namespace MyProject.Models
        {

public partial class ReAdvSlot
            {
// Poco
                public int AdvSlotId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public string Notes { get; set; }
            }

        }
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

        namespace MyProject.Models
        {
            [MetadataType(typeof(ReAdvSlotMetaData))]
            public partial class ReAdvSlot
            {
                public class ReAdvSlotMetaData
                {
                    public int AdvSlotId { get; set; }
                    public string Name { get; set; }
                    public string Description { get; set; }
                    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
                    public string Code { get; set; }
                    public string Notes { get; set; }
                    public string TestProperty { get; set; } // TEST PROPERTY
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here." - nor am I - you haven't told us what the problem is (that I can see)

Comment: Thanks Damien, I edit my question, the problem is that the METADATA in the partial class do hot apply soit seems the partial class is ignored

Comment: Have you tried [MetadataType(typeof(ReAdvSlot.ReAdvSlotMetaData))] or moving the metadata class out of the main class (not both at the same time oviously)? Sometimes the examples on MSDN are wrong, and in this case the VB example had the matadata outside the main class.

Answer (score 0):

The partial class is not ignored. If you were to put Test property into the actual partial class instead of the metadata, you would see it in the class definition.

```
    namespace MyProject.Models
    {

        public partial class ReAdvSlot
            {
                public int AdvSlotId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public string Notes { get; set; }
            }

        }
    }

    namespace MyProject.Models
    {
        [MetadataType(typeof(ReAdvSlotMetaData))]
        public partial class ReAdvSlot
        {
             public string TestProperty { get; set; } // TEST PROPERTY here instead
        }

        public class ReAdvSlotMetaData
            {
                [Required] //Example of defining metadata
                public int AdvSlotId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public string Notes { get; set; }

            }
    }
```